# How to calculate the probability of two events happening simultaneously

Tags: probability

I am imagining a scenario of an open bowl of tickets with numbers from 1 - 10. If two people were to draw at the same time, would I have to do anything different towards the probability of person1 drawing a certain number?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to imagine that the two choices can be made ***absolutely*** simultaneously, but that could be modeled. Three solutions:

- If A goes first she has probability $1/10$ of getting the `5`.
- If B goes first, he gets the `5` with probability $1/10$ and A has no chance of getting the `5`, or he doesn't take the `5` and then A has chance $1/9$ of getting the `5`, so her probability of getting the 5 is again $(1/10)(0)+(9/10)(1/9) = 1/10.$
- If we pretend two numbers are chosen simultaneously, the probability one of them is the `5` is $\frac{{1\choose 1}{9\choose 1}}{{10\choose 2}} = 2/10.$
  Conditionally on that, the  probability it was A who got the `5` is $1/2.$
  So her chance of having the `5` is $(2/10)(1/2) = 1/10.$

Perhaps more formally, let $D_5$ be the event that `5` was drawn and $A_5 \subset D_5$ be
the event that A drew the `5`. Then $$P(A_5) = P(A_5D_5) = P(D_5)P(A_5|D_5) = (2/10)(1/2) = 1/10.$$

```
choose(1,1)*choose(9,1)/choose(10,2)
[1] 0.2
```